# Anyway to do a "key-logging" on other applications on Android?

Tags: android, logging, keyboard

Sorry if my question is too basic. Is there any way to read in my application the input entered on other applications?

Thank you so much

Comment: What application is this, those of us with privacy concerns would really like to know?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be possible to track access key strokes from apps. The design of android lets each app as a different Virtual Machine and thus doesn't allow such sniffing activities.

However there are few sniffing apps available on playstore which grab some sensitive information like GPS location info and other stuff from the logs.

But the things you are looking for (Key loggers) are not present!

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, this is not possible (except on a rooted device), for obvious privacy and security reasons.